# How to search for a point in a text file of many points?

Tags: python

I have two text files; the first containing a group of points of x and y, and the second has much more points of x,y and z including the first file points. I want to search for each point of the first file in the second one to get the z coordinate. I have made that in python but it's taking too much time! so if any one has a faster code i would be glad

```
with open('D:/Point cloud data/Data mabna 4/Data_without_RGB/Downsampled/Walls_only_downsampled_5cm.txt') as f1, open("D:/Point cloud data/Data mabna 4/Data_without_RGB/Downsampled/Walls_only_3d.txt", 'a') as f3:

    for line in f1:
        E, N = line.split()
        E = float(E)
        E = float("{0:.3f}".format(E))
        N = float(N)
        N = float("{0:.3f}".format(N))
        with open('D:/Point cloud data/Data mabna 4/Data_without_RGB/Downsampled/Combined_cropped_downsampled_5cm.txt') as f2:
            for row in f2:
                x, y, z = row.split()
                x = float(x)
                x = float("{0:.3f}".format(x))
                y = float(y)
                y = float("{0:.3f}".format(y))

                if E==x and N==y:
                    f3.write(row)
```

Comment: can you please provide some example data of your first text file?

Comment: Note that it is slow because you are reading the large file for **every** point you want to find. And you keep reading the file even after you found the point (I'm assuming they are unique)

Comment: yes I know that but couldn't find other way ... I will try your suggestion and tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your files are not so large that you cannot store all of them in memory. Also, I'm assuming you have one file with a lot of points (the one with the z-coordinates, that I will call `full_coord`) and the files with the points you want to find the z-coordinate, that I will call `partial_coord`.

The idea is to read `full_coord` in memory and put it in a dictionary, so that you can look it up by `(x, y)` and get a triple `(x, y, z)` as a result. Reading files (and manipulating strings) is about 1 million times slower than manipulating things in memory. Accessing dictionaries (even large ones) in Python is very fast, close to O(1). This should work without issues in a modern machine for a few tens of millions of points.

At last, based on your code, I'm assuming you are only interested in a precision of 3 decimal places, so all entries can be truncated (I'll truncate in the key only, so the output will be full precision).

Note that the code below assumes that the `(x, y)` coordinates of a point define the `z` coordinate uniquely. If there are several points with the same `(x, y)` but different `z`, the code has to be changed (it is an easy change using a `defaultdict`).

```py
precision = 3
full_coord_filename = r'file_with_z_coord.txt'
partial_coord_filename = r'file_with_partial_coordinates.txt'

full_coord_points = {}
with open(full_coord_filename, 'r') as fh:
  for i, row in enumerate(fh):
    x, y ,z = row.split()
    key = (round(float(x), precision), round(float(y), precision))
    if key in full_coord_points:  # Check cases in which the rounding is overlapping points
      print(f'Warning: Found repeated key: {key}, in row {i}')
    full_coord_points[key] = row  # We can save the row as a string

points_to_search = []
with open(partial_coord_filename, 'r') as fh:
  for row in fh:
    x, y = row.split()
    points_to_search.append((round(float(x), precision), round(float(y), precision)))  # Also an (x, y) tuple

# Search for all the points and collect the results. Also collect the points that were not found
found = []
not_found = []
for point in points_to_search:
  try:
    found.append(full_coord_points[point])
  except KeyError:
    not_found.append(point)

# you can save your list of found points
with open('output_file.txt', 'w') as fh:
  for row in found:
    fh.write(row)

# And print the points that were not found
print('The following points were not found:')
for point in not_found:
  print(point)
```